# android listview adapter throw exception

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter, android-adapterview

i build an adapter for a listview_item which contains image, textview and textbox, i don't know why the application throw an exception,

```
class RestaurantAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    Activity activity;

    public RestaurantAdapter(Activity activity,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.activity = activity;
        this.data = data;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View vi = convertView;
        if (vi == null)
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.restaurant_multi_select_list_item, null);
         TextView name = (TextView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.restaurant_multi_select_title);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.restaurant_multi_select_list_item_image);
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.restaurant_multi_select_checkBox);
        HashMap<String, String> restaurant = data.get(position);
        name.setText(restaurant.get("name"));
        cb.setSelected(false);
        image.setId(Integer.parseInt(restaurant.get("image")));
        return vi;

    }
}
```

when i made the `getview` contains just this code

```
View vi = convertView;
            if (vi == null)
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.restaurant_multi_select_list_item, null);
```

it still throws the exception

if you want any another code i will give it to you

thanks

## edit

exception

```
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1521)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1749)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:731)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1602)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1349)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7320)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1263)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1137)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1051)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7320)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:342)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7320)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1263)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1137)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1051)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7320)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:342)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7320)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1162)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1882)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
01-23 19:45:27.021: E/AndroidRuntime(24106):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

## the new exception

```
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at com.eattel.syriatel.RestaurantAdapter.getView(Select_Multi_Restaurants.java:113)
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1294)
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:623)
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:2944)
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:2065)
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3315)
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3766)
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:897)
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1671)
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086)
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1655)
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1785)
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-22 12:36:37.994: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post LogCat so we can help

Comment: Which exception? I can't see any in your post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `vi == null` then you have to set the inflater to `vi`. otherwise you are trying to get a view from nothing or `null`

for example

```
if (vi == null)
       vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.restaurant_multi_select_list_item, null);
```

Comment: thanks alot, +1 for u , i accept Mistsuaki's answer, because he answer me first

Comment: same exception? if not post the new one

Comment: @tyczjj i posted the new exception

Comment: try not setting `vi` to `contentView` and just set `vi` to the `inflater view` like you would in the check real quick. Also where is line `113`?

Comment: line 113 is this `image.setId(Integer.parseInt(restaurant.get("image")));`

Comment: Either the values `restaurant` is null (but if its passing the `restaurant.get("name")` its probably not) or the data for the "image" is null or incorrect hard to tell from what is given, set a breakpoint in there and see what the image value is before passing it into the `ImageView`

Comment: how to make a break point ? and how to see the image value then ?

Comment: if you are in eclipse click on the line before that line and on the far left in the margin its blueish double click on that line and you will see a blue dot appear and thats a breakpoint. now start a new debugging session and it will stop at that line. If you are having problems getting it you will need to look it up but the problem is probably not anything related to your original question and has more to do with the data in there

Comment: `image ImageView  (id=830085571400)` i got this value

Comment: also i got this `convertView null`

Comment: i use this code from this site http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/ now i rememberd that he use a class to show the image , have i used it too ?

Comment: if that "image"value is the image resource id like `r.id.image` for example and all you are doing is trying to show an image the you are using the wrong method. you need to use `image.setImageResource(restaurant.get("image"));` if thats not the problem its best to start a new question as this is out of the scope of the origional

Comment: yes baby :), setimageresourse works and the exception goes , thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu

Comment: you can get to all the views in Window > show View and pick the view you want back

Answer (score 1):

I think...

```
vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.restaurant_multi_select_list_item, null);
```

Comment: it works , but when i tried to scroll the items, i got an exception , why please?

Comment: give me your stack trace? (Exception)

Comment: Thanks! Would you show me the line 133 of Select_Multi_Restaurants.java.

Comment: there is no 133 line :), it is just 119

Comment: And It may not be concerned with your problem.
* If vi( == convertView ) is not null…, what is happen?
* findViewById is called everytime when each list item data is assigned. This is not faster ListView.
Check out following URL?(*´ω｀*)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431420/i-need-to-add-a-imageview-or-webview-in-my-listview/14457392#14457392

Comment: if it is not null , the app will contine from this `TextView name = (TextView) vi
    .findViewById(R.id.restaurant_multi_select_title);` this is not wrong i am sure of that, don't worry about null or not , it is 100% correct, i am confuse now why is exception when scroll the listview

Comment: +1 for u , i hope i could accept more than one answer ,realy thank you